# como apertar o botão usando código, usando o mesmo efeito de quando o usuario aperta

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

estou fazendo o jogo para java e ao iniciar a maquina vai dar uma sequecia de cliques aleatória em 4 botões e depois o usuario tem que apertar igual a maquina, mas não sei como fazer a maquina apertar o botão

```
package gênius;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class tela extends JFrame {

    //nome do jogador e pontos
    int pontos = 0 ;
    String usuario = "";

    //varieaveis de jogadas
    String jjogador = "";
    String maquina ="";


    // janela de exibição
    public void janela(){
        JFrame  ftela = new JFrame();
        ftela.setTitle("Gênius");
        ftela.setSize(400, 600);
        ftela.setBackground(Color.white);
        ftela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ftela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ftela.setVisible(true);


        //boões de ção
        JButton b1 = new JButton("");
        b1.setBounds(100, 220, 80, 80);
        b1.setVisible(true);
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);


        JButton b2 = new JButton("");
        b2.setBounds(200, 220, 80, 80);
        b2.setVisible(true);
        b2.setBackground(Color.red);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("");
        b3.setBounds(100, 320, 80, 80);
        b3.setVisible(true);
        b3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JButton b4 = new JButton("");
        b4.setBounds(200, 320, 80, 80);
        b4.setVisible(true);
        b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        JButton b5 = new JButton("vermalho");
        b5.setBounds(200, 420, 80, 80);
        b5.setVisible(true);
        b5.getColorModel();
        b5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        ftela.add(b1);
        ftela.add(b2);
        ftela.add(b3);
        ftela.add(b4);
        ftela.add(b5);


        //ações dos botôes
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b1");
                jjogador += " "+0;

            }
        });
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b2");
                jjogador += " "+1;

            }
        });
       b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b3");
                jjogador += " "+2;

            }
        });
       b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play("b4");
                jjogador += " "+3;

            }
        });

       b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jjogador);

            }
        });





    }
     // coloando som no botão 
        public void play(String audio){
            URL url = getClass().getResource(audio+".wav");
            AudioClip  audioc = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
            audioc.play();
        }

        public void jlabe (){
            JLabel mPontos = new JLabel("pontos ");
            mPontos.setText("pontos :"+pontos);
            mPontos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        }

}
```

Comment: Acho que entendi, mas sua abordagem está equivocada, vou tentar fazer um exemplo aqui de uma forma que pode atender.

Comment: por favor , estou meio enrolado pois nem sei o que usar para fazer isso

Comment: você sabe fazer ?

Comment: Tem como você adicionar o que já fez na pergunta? Mostrar do zero vai acabar gerando uma reposta mais complexa do que o necessário para a questão, é mais facil tentar alto a partir do seu ponto de partida.

Comment: tem sim vou adicionar

Answer (score 2):

Há varias maneiras de se adicionar ação ao JButton, talvez a mais simples seja por classe anônima:

```
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //evento aqui
        }
    });
```

Esta forma é muito usada quando não se tem nada de muito complexo na ação.
Se estiver usandojava 8, as coisas ficam bem mais fáceis:

```
b1.addActionListener(e -> {
            //ação aqui
        });
```

Comment: não, isso ai eu fiz mas quero apertar esse botão usando código eu já vi robot mas robot tem que mover o mouse queria algo mais direto

Comment: @DiogoCipriano não entendi, na pergunta, você questiona como adicionar um ação no Jbutton apenas.

Comment: a pessoa vai na tela e aperta o botão correto, eu queria apertar o botão usando código

Comment: @DiogoCipriano creio então que esta não seja a abordagem correta a se seguir. O que ou qual componente vai disparar a ação do botao? Edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes do que está tentando fazer e do que precisa fazer.

Comment: quero usar um for, e quando jogador clicar no botão iniciar usarei um random para que quando quando o random gerar 1 o código clique no botão 1, e não o usuario

Comment: @DiogoCipriano pra que usar botão para isso? Talvez seja melhor você usar um método que receba esse valor gerado, você trata esse valor e executa a ação de acordo com o valor passado. Da pra fazer isso usando switch...case, mas você teria que fazer o que te orientei, editar a pergunta e fornecer melhores detalhes sobre o que está fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais fácil é assim:
Adicionas a acção ao Button:

```
b1.addActionListener(this);
```

Depois vais criar essa acção:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //O código que queiras
}
```

Porém, para que esta maneira seja possível, tens de implementar uma `ActionListener`:

```
public class NOME_DA_CLASSE implements ActionListener{
    //Código    
}
```

Comment: O que o `this` representa? Porque se a classe não for uma actionListener, seu código vai falhar.

Comment: Sim Diego F, temos de colocar isso.
public class NOME_DA_CLASSE implements ActionListener

Comment: Obrigado, vou já actualizar para que fique claro.

Comment: Obrigado Diego F, vou já actualizar