# ActionListener não identifica o botão recuperado

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Meu objetivo é clicar no botão `Andar` e depois selecionar no tabuleiro para qual direção o personagem será movido, como mostra a imagem:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Meu botão `Andar` possui um `ActionListener` e é tratado da seguinte forma:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object escolha = e.getSource();

    if(escolha==andar)
        moverHumano(escolha);
}
```

Porém, o tipo "`Object escolha`" parece não detectar ação alguma dentro da classe "`moverHumano`", mesmo após ter adicionado os `ActionListener` nas posições do lado do personagem.

Esse if, por exemplo, nunca é entendido como true:

```
if(escolha == this.tabela[POSIÇÃO X][POSIÇÃO Y])
```

O que quero fazer é possível dessa forma?

Abaixo, o código da classe MAIN:

```
    package teste;
public class TESTE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tabuleiro cenario = new Tabuleiro();
        cenario.criarTela();
    }

}
```

Classe TABULEIRO:

```
package teste;

public class Tabuleiro extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton tabela[][],andar,cura,sair,debug,percepcao,vida;
    private GridLayout layoutTabuleiro;
    Humano jogador1;

    public Tabuleiro(){ 
        super("Zumbicídio");
        setSize(800,600);
        setResizable(false);
        layoutTabuleiro = new GridLayout(14,14);
         setSize(800,600);
        jogador1 = new Humano();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void criarTela(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //ADICIONANDO ELEMENTOS
        this.visualizarTabuleiro();
        //MOSTRANDO A JANELA
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    //No método abaixo eu adiciono tudo no tabuleiro, por isso ficou grande, mas boa parte pode ser ignorada. Acho que o que importa mesmo é ter adicionado os ActionListener, o que fiz logo no início. Adicionei printf's de teste nos locais que não funcionam no meu código original (isso tá lá embaixo, perto do método do ActionListener)
    public void visualizarTabuleiro(){
    final JPanel telaTabuleiro = new JPanel();
    int i, j;

    telaTabuleiro.setLayout(layoutTabuleiro);
    telaTabuleiro.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,550));

    // ADICIONANDO ACTION LISTENER
    tabela = new JButton[10][10];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){      
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            this.tabela[i][j] = new JButton(new ImageIcon("res/images/desconhecido.png/"));
            this.tabela[i][j].addActionListener(this);  
        }
    }

    //ADICIONANDO ELEMENTOS

    //1 LINHA
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //2 LINHA (PRIMEIRA DO TABULEIRO) **************

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[0][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //3 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[1][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //4 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[2][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //5 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[3][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //6 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[4][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //7 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[5][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //8 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[6][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //9 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[7][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //10 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[8][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //11 LINHA

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        telaTabuleiro.add(tabela[9][j]);
    }
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //12 LINHA
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //13 LINHA
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    vida = new JButton("hp");
    telaTabuleiro.add(vida);
    percepcao = new JButton("percep");

    telaTabuleiro.add(percepcao);

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    andar = new JButton("andar");
    andar.addActionListener(this);
    telaTabuleiro.add(andar);

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    cura = new JButton("cura");
    cura.addActionListener(this);
    telaTabuleiro.add(cura);

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    debug = new JButton("debug");
    debug.addActionListener(this);
    telaTabuleiro.add(debug);
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    sair = new JButton("sair");
    sair.addActionListener(this);
    telaTabuleiro.add(sair);
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //14 LINHA
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label("    Vida "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label("  Percep. "));

    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label("   Andar"));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label("   Cura"));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label("   Debug"));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label("     Sair"));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));
    telaTabuleiro.add(new Label(" "));

    //ADICIONANDO NO CONTENTPANE
    this.getContentPane().add(telaTabuleiro, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public void moverHumano(Object escolha){
    if(escolha==tabela[0][0]){
        System.out.println("Selecionou a primeira posição!"); // O QUE DESEJO TESTAR E NÃO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {  
    Object escolha = ae.getSource();
    if(escolha==andar){
        System.out.println("Escolheu andar");
        moverHumano(escolha);
    }
}
```

Classe HUMANO:

```
    package teste;
public class Humano {
    private int saude, percep;
    Humano(){
        this.saude = 5;
        this.percep = 3;
    }

    public int getSaude(){
        return this.saude;
    }   

    public int getPercepcao(){
        return this.percep;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei alguns erros e os listei para que você verifique se podem ser o causadores do problema:

- Todas as aplicações gráficas envolvendo a API swing devem ser [**despachadas para a EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595);
- Não utilize a classe [`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html). Se está programando em java-swing, o componente que deve ser utilizado é [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html). É preciso ficar atento a isso, pois quase todos os componentes do pacote [`javax.swing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) tem equivalentes no [`java.awt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html), e como swing é uma evolução do awt, você deve sempre utilizar os componentes do pacote `javax.swing`;
- não há necessidade de implementar `ActionListener` em um `JFrame`. Se for aplicar o listener apenas a um botão, faça isso [**adicionando o listener inline**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129135/28595) ou se o listener for aplicado a outros botoes, crie uma classe a parte isolada que implemente a interface `ActionListener`.
- Tanto no método `moverHumano()` quanto no `ActionListener`, você está tratando um componente botão como `Object`, e tentando comparar a uma variável do tipo `JButton`, e essa verificação jamais será verdadeira, mesmo que ali seja passado o mesmo componente. Dentro do `actionPerformed()` você precisa fazer o cast para `JButton` antes de comparar:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    JButton escolha = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    if (escolha == andar) {
        System.out.println("Escolheu andar");
        moverHumano(escolha);
    }
}
```

E no método `moverHumano()`, ao invés de receber um `Object`, altere para `JButton`. Lembrando que pelo simples fato da listener ser aplicada a um botão, nesta condição fazer o cast será sempre seguro, apenas atente-se para casos onde se compartilha o listener com componentes diferentes(como entre `JButton` e `JToggleButton`).